# shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb => new shopify-cli package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to install the Shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb , But I am receiving the error.
I already executed the command
**sudo gem update --system 3.1.3
sudo apt-get install -y ruby-dev**

but when I am trying to install the **Shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb**  using the following command I am receiving a error:

```
``
**sudo apt install /home/daviamaral/Downloads/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb**

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
 be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.3 for inspe
ction.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.3/g
em_make.out
dpkg: error processing archive /home/daviamaral/Downloads/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb 
(--unpack):
 new shopify-cli package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/daviamaral/Downloads/shopify-cli-2.1.0.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I am going to the   /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.3/mkmf.log

```
"pkg-config --exists libffi"
package configuration for libffi is not found
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.7.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.7-2E2p8v/ruby2.7-2.7.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.7  -lm   -lc"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I wrote this question I rested In my thoughts and realized the problem was being shown in the log!

==> package configuration for libffi is not found

yeah, for me, it's just the gcc environment, so I  tried
**sudo apt-get install gcc**
That worked for me in ubuntu!

I will keep the question here because could be a problem for another person in the future!